# InAppBrowser Should Use a Background Thread Warning

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, inappbrowser

I am using PhoneGap/Cordova and Ionic / Angular with Firebase Simple Login for Facebook.  I have a button on my login page that should call auth.login().  This works in Chrome, but when I click it while it is running on my iPhone 5s (iOS7) through xCode, I get the following error:

```
2014-07-07 18:47:44.921 HOST-ENTOURAGE[650:60b] Setting the WebView's frame to {{0, 0}, {320, 524}}
2014-07-07 18:47:44.928 HOST-ENTOURAGE[650:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '40.712158' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-07-07 18:47:47.029 HOST-ENTOURAGE[650:60b] {"code":"UNKNOWN_ERROR"}
```

Things I have tried:

1. Deleted my inappbrowser plugin folder, ios.json file, and ios platform folder.  Then did a rebuild.
2. Device emulator also doesn't work
3. Minimizing the app and reopening doesn't fix
4. I tried reordering my scripts in index.html (ie putting cordova.js first)

Repo is here: [Host Entourage Repo](https://github.com/liebeskind/Host-Entourage)

I have struggled with this for hours, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: Here is the code I'm using.  Thanks Kato for pointing out that this would be more useful!

```
var chatRef = new Firebase('https://host-entourage.firebaseio.com');
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
      $rootScope.$apply(function(){$location.path('/main/login/loginchoice'); });
      isLoggedIn = true;
      console.log('User ID: ' + user.uid + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
    } else {
      console.log('Not logged in');
    }
  });
```

For the button functionality:

```
login: function() {
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        auth.login('facebook', {
          rememberMe: true,
          scope: 'email,public_profile'
        });
      } else {
        $location.path('/main/login/loginchoice')
      }
```

```

Comment: Instead of providing the code repo and asking us to debug this, could you instead offer a small sample of code we can run that reproduces the error? It doesn't have to be a complete app, but just something that demonstrates the issue. Often, in doing this due diligence, you'll expose the bug in the process as well. Win-win.

Comment: The plugin warning is not your issue, many of the Cordova plugins cause this warning to throw to console [see this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370598/thread-warnings-in-phonegap-cordova-app). have you tried peppering your code with console.log() to see where your call gets?

Comment: Thanks islanddave.  The if(error) { console.log(error) } line is throwing the {"code":"UNKNOWN_ERROR"}.  No user is being passed into the FirebaseSimpleLogin callback.  I'll mess around with changing parameters in auth.login and let you know if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately, getting rid of the parameters for auth.login doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: Wanted to let everyone know that I solved this by using the phonegap-facebook-plugin and passing the access token to auth.login().

Answer (score 0):

One possible suggestion is to check your API/KEY settings, as found in [this thread dealing with Twitter / Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104121/i-receive-an-firebasesimplelogin-an-unknown-error-occurred-in-firebase-when-i).

If that isn't your issue, the [Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html) says to contact support@firebase.com when you encounter UNKNOWN_ERROR.

Comment: Thanks @islanddave.  My API/Key settings are correct so I shot support@ an email.  Will post when it gets resolved.